# How to install Edubuntu from Xubuntu in the terminal

Tags: xubuntu, edubuntu

We are formatting 20 machines to use in LATAM. We need to install Edubuntu from Xubuntu. How can we install it from the terminal?

We're www.notegood.org, and www.comparte.org, NGOs from Barcelona. We reformat old portables to use in poor LATAM school. We started by installing Xubuntu in 20 machines, now we discovered Edubuntu, and we want to upgrade these machines. Can we update Xubuntu to Edubuntu from the terminal, or do we have install Edubuntu from a bootable USB?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by "installing edubuntu from xubuntu"? Do you just want the edubuntu look + feel + applications or do you want to do a complete reinstall of edubuntu?

Comment: @Seth I have added the reply to your comment that the OP posted to his question.

Answer (score 1):

Just install [`edubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/edubuntu-desktop):

```
sudo apt-get install edubuntu-desktop
```

As this is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) this will install the desktop environment, and you can select the installed DE from the login screen.

Comment: and from gnome?   this message in terminal E: No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos, ¿quizás deba ejecutar «apt-get update» o deba intentarlo de nuevo con --fix-missing?
notegood@notegood-Latitude-D630:~$ ^C

Comment: Try running `apt-get update`, also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/462690/178596). If you are using old unsupported Ubuntu release [(not 12.04/14.04/14.10)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)