# After interrupting an update Ubuntu says there is nothing more to do, but it did warn me that it had not finished

Tags: apt, upgrade

I just ran:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And it went like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  clamav clamav-base clamav-freshclam cups-browsed cups-filters
  cups-filters-core-drivers libclamav7 libcupsfilters1 libfontembed1
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text
  ubuntu-gnome-default-settings xdiagnose
13 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 3,407 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,120 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 clamav-base all 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2 [57.9 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libclamav7 amd64 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2 [751 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 clamav-freshclam amd64 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2 [115 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 clamav amd64 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2 [97.5 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 cups-browsed amd64 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 [92.7 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libcupsfilters1 amd64 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 [80.4 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 cups-filters-core-drivers amd64 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 [127 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libfontembed1 amd64 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 [47.1 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 cups-filters amd64 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 [448 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo all 16.04.5 [82.7 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text all 16.04.5 [3,884 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 ubuntu-gnome-default-settings all 16.04.5 [1,439 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 xdiagnose all 3.8.4.1 [64.3 kB]
Fetched 3,407 kB in 10s (321 kB/s)                                             
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 248174 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../clamav-base_0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking clamav-base (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) over (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libclamav7_0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libclamav7 (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) over (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../clamav-freshclam_0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking clamav-freshclam (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) over (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../clamav_0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking clamav (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) over (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../cups-browsed_1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-browsed (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) over (1.8.3-2ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libcupsfilters1_1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcupsfilters1:amd64 (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) over (1.8.3-2ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../cups-filters-core-drivers_1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-filters-core-drivers (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) over (1.8.3-2ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libfontembed1_1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfontembed1:amd64 (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) over (1.8.3-2ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../cups-filters_1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-filters (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) over (1.8.3-2ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo_16.04.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo (16.04.5) over (16.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text_16.04.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text (16.04.5) over (16.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-gnome-default-settings_16.04.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-gnome-default-settings (16.04.5) over (16.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../xdiagnose_3.8.4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xdiagnose (3.8.4.1) over (3.8.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up clamav-base (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libclamav7 (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up clamav-freshclam (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
To check for updates more often than hourly, please run freshclam as a daemon.
Replacing config file /etc/cron.d/clamav-freshclam with new version
Starting database update: 
ClamAV update process started at Wed Aug 31 21:55:33 2016
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.99 Recommended version: 0.99.2
DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq
main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
Downloading daily-22162.cdiff [100%]
daily.cld updated (version: 22162, sigs: 568963, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Empty script safebrowsing-44985.cdiff, need to download entire database
nonblock_recv: recv timing out (30 secs)
WARNING: getfile: Download interrupted: Operation now in progress (IP: 193.1.193.64)
WARNING: Can't download safebrowsing.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Trying again in 5 secs...
ClamAV update process started at Wed Aug 31 21:58:41 2016
WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net
WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
Reading CVD header (main.cvd): 
WARNING: Can't get information about db.local.clamav.net: Name or service not known
WARNING: Can't read main.cvd header from db.local.clamav.net (IP: )
Trying again in 5 secs...
ClamAV update process started at Wed Aug 31 21:59:31 2016
WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net
WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
Reading CVD header (main.cvd): 
WARNING: Can't get information about db.local.clamav.net: Name or service not known
WARNING: Can't read main.cvd header from db.local.clamav.net (IP: )
Trying again in 5 secs...
ClamAV update process started at Wed Aug 31 22:00:16 2016
WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net
WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
Reading CVD header (main.cvd): OK
main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
Reading CVD header (daily.cvd): OK (IMS)
daily.cld is up to date (version: 22162, sigs: 568963, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Reading CVD header (safebrowsing.cvd): OK
Empty script safebrowsing-44985.cdiff, need to download entire database
nonblock_recv: recv timing out (30 secs)
WARNING: getfile: Download interrupted: Operation now in progress (IP: 129.67.1.218)
WARNING: Can't download safebrowsing.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Trying again in 5 secs...
ClamAV update process started at Wed Aug 31 22:01:24 2016
WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net
WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
Reading CVD header (main.cvd): Trying host db.local.clamav.net (81.91.100.173)...
OK
main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
Reading CVD header (daily.cvd): OK (IMS)
daily.cld is up to date (version: 22162, sigs: 568963, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Reading CVD header (safebrowsing.cvd): OK
Empty script safebrowsing-44985.cdiff, need to download entire database
Downloading safebrowsing.cvd [100%]
safebrowsing.cvd updated (version: 44985, sigs: 2940762, f-level: 63, builder: google)
Reading CVD header (bytecode.cvd): OK (IMS)
bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 283, sigs: 53, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Database updated (7728568 signatures) from db.local.clamav.net (IP: 81.91.100.173)
ERROR: NotifyClamd: Can't find or parse configuration file /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
Setting up clamav (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up cups-browsed (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libcupsfilters1:amd64 (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up cups-filters-core-drivers (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libfontembed1:amd64 (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up cups-filters (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...

Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo (16.04.5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text (16.04.5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up ubuntu-gnome-default-settings (16.04.5) ...
Setting up xdiagnose (3.8.4.1) ...
Processing triggers for cups (2.1.3-4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

You will see that the ClamAV operation was doing so well, so I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> a few times, though this had no impact on the ClamAV Freshclam updater which was running. However later on (as you will see right at the end) it says that the operations was interrupted before it could finish.

I have tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` as is normally recommended, however neither of those commands return any error nor think there is anything more which needs doing. There is also no error when running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again, though there are no new packages to install.

I still feel uneasy though, is there anything I should do? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 with GNOME 3.20, should I perhaps reinstall all the packages it was upgrading there or can I check what else needs doing?

Comment: Tip: Never, EVER, try to stop an `apt` operation. If you don't want it, wait for it to finish and then remove it. This is how I broke my computer once!

Comment: @moo_we_all_do: I didn't want to stop the rest of the `apt` operation, in fact I wanted the packages to be upgraded, it just got stuck on the clamav update for some reason so that's what I wanted to stop, not the whole thing. I thought I'd be able to start it all up afterwards though, but apparently not... I will be more careful in future, but it just seemed stuck, I didn't know what to do.

Comment: @moo_we_all_do I've done that too. Never again!

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I'd joke that ClamAv probably has a virus but that might make you paranoid. [This link talks about rebuilding depednancies](http://askubuntu.com/questions/462690/what-does-apt-get-fix-missing-do-and-when-is-it-useful/462751)

Comment: Might thw warning be from `update-initramfs` instead of `apt-get` maybe? Just a thought...

Comment: @ByteCommander: I think you're maybe right, it doesn't seem to do anything after that.

Comment: In that case you might simply run `sudo update-initramfs -uk all` to update/rebuild all known initramfs. It can not hurt anyway.