# I accidentally did apt-get remove python. Tried all solution

Tags: 16.04, python3, aptdaemon

I accidentally did apt-get remove python3. I tried sudo `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` but it shows

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptdaemon : Depends: python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14.1) but 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 is to be installed
```

Whatever solution i try it says the above error. Please someone help me.

**EDIT**
I tried `sudo -i python3-aptdaemon.deb`.But it is showing

```
    /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: 
    Too many levels of symbolic links dpkg: error processing archive 
    ./python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14_all.deb (-install): subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 2 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.postinst: 6: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.postinst: py3compile: Too
 many levels of symbolic links
```

Whenever I try to install any .deb file it says

```
python3-all depends on python3 (= 3.5.1-3); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
```

Comment: Check you have the xenial-updates in your sources (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-aptdaemon&searchon=names)

Comment: `apt-get update --fix-missing` Ref: http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/

Comment: Thanks for the response @EODCraftStaff. I did it and it executed the code but still it shows  aptdaemon : `Depends: python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14.1) but 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 is to be installed` when I do `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thanks for the response @guiverc. How do I install the updates?

Comment: There is a variety of those `--fix-missing` like `install`, none work? Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/462690/what-does-apt-get-fix-missing-do-and-when-is-it-useful/462751

Comment: Because you removed `python3`, tools that use or require it will have issues.  I would use `wget` to download the .deb files you need and use `dpkg` to install them. This will mark them as manually installed, which if it worries you, you could always use `apt-mark` to reverse but I don't see that it matters. fyi: you may find yourself needing to `wget` multiple files to install (`apt` tools will do this for you automatically, `dpkg` won't)

Comment: Iam new to ubuntu. please say the exact command to do it.

Comment: Google will teach you most Linux commands, it will take some effort on your part and you will become a better admin of your system for it. It may even help you avoid removing things you require in the future.

Comment: But please help me. I am worried now.

Comment: I downloaded .deb file and did `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file`. But it shows `/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.postinst: py3compile: Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: Please don't add additional information in comments, it's hard to read & your last comment was 'hidden' by default (where you want it read - edit your question and put it there). If you're asking someone a specific question you need to tag them, as it's only chance I returned here.  The "/path/to/deb/file" should have been replaced by your path and filename. Full commands & output are easier to read than snippets (and questions/answers allow formatting)

Comment: @guiverc. Iam sorry. I tried the command and it shows `/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.postinst: py3compile: Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Correction: apt-get does not require python, so you should be able to reinstall normally:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
sudo apt-get install python3-aptdaemon
```

apt dependencies:

> Depends: adduser, gpgv | gpgv2 | gpgv1, ubuntu-keyring, libapt-pkg5.0
>   (>= 1.7.0~alpha3~), libc6 (>= 2.15), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libgnutls30
>   (>= 3.6.5), libseccomp2 (>= 1.0.1), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)

python3-aptdaemon dependencies:

> Depends: python3:any (>= 3.2~), aptdaemon, gir1.2-glib-2.0,
>   gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 (>= 1.1.1), python3-apt (>= 0.8.5~ubuntu1),
>   python3-defer (>= 1.0.6), python3-dbus, python3-gi,
>   python3-pkg-resources, iso-codes Filename:
>   pool/main/a/aptdaemon/python3-aptdaemon_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu21_all.deb

Comment: Thanks a lot Wayne. I tried install python3-aptdaemon. it is  showing    `/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing archive ./python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.postinst: py3compile: Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: @Melebius. Now I added the outputs in my question. Please help me.

Comment: @Wayne Vosberg .Thanks a lot for  your answers. I fixed it by removing the symbolic links and install ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: I still receive `python3 is not yet configured`. Do you any idea how to solve it? @Wayne Vosberg

Comment: `sudo apt-get reinstall python3` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3` possibly.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne. It says `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: python3 is broken or not fully installed`.